# Graph Data Science Error (APOC Metadata Procedure Unavailable)

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc, graph-data-science

I have imported my data into my dbms and installed the plugins APOC (4.2.0.0) and the Graf Data Science Library (1.4.1).

When I open the playground i get the following error:

[error-msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YlKs.png)

I added following lines into my neo4j config,

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=jwt.security.*,apoc.*,gds.*
dbms.security.procedures.allowlist=jwt.security.*,apoc.*,gds.*
```

but still getting the same error.

I have done a little research and found someone with the same error and he said:

"It turned out to be a problem with the schema - I had a node with a label that had a space in it "

Is that really an option it is not working for me?

I did my import with neo4j-admin like this:

```
bin/neo4j-admin import --database=neo4j --id-type=INTEGER --multiline-fields=true --skip-duplicate-nodes --skip-bad-relationships=true --nodes=commits=import/nodes-commits.csv --nodes=packages=import/nodes-packages.csv --nodes=users=import/nodes-users.csv --relationships=commits=import/relationship-projects_commits.csv
```

with some further relationships.

I also tried then newest version of the dbms, apoc and GDS, but the same error came up.

Anybody have any idea if it can be the import or is it some other error.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which Neo4j version are you using? are you sure that apoc 4.2.0.0 is the correct version for your Neo4j?

Comment: Im using version 1.4.7. I also tried different versions (APOC and GDSL) and the error is the same.
When I remove the relationship (relationship-project_commits.csv), the error disappeared and I can start the "playground". There might be a error in the relationship. 

I checked the the file ones again, but don't know what could be the error.
File looks like this:

:START_ID(project-id) :END_ID(commit-id)
1 1540 26801
2 1540 26805
3 1540 26809
4 1540 26812

Comment: This is really weird, can you share the data to reproduce at https://github.com/neo4j-devtools/neuler/issues

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I made a new issue.
https://github.com/neo4j-devtools/neuler/issues/131